# python multiprocessing example itertools multiple lists

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have a very simple application with a nested for-loop and it can take minutes to hours to run depending on the amount of data.

I got started with the multiprocessing lib in python.  I tried implementing it in is most basic form, and even though my code runs, there are no performance gains.  Leading me to believe I am implementing it incorrectly and/or the design of my code is extremely flawed.

My code is pretty straight forward:

```
import csv
import multiprocessing

somedata1 = open('data1.csv', 'r')
SD_data = csv.reader(data1,delimiter=',')
data1 = []
**import lots of CSV data***

def crunchnumbers():
   for i, vald1 in enumerate(data1):
        for i, vald2 in enumerate(data2):
            for i, vald3 in enumerate(data3):   
                for i, vald4 in enumerate(data3):
                    for i, vald5 in enumerate(data3):
                         sol = #add values
    print d_solution

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.apply(crunchnumbers)
```

How can I do this with python's multiprocessing? (somehow spliting into chunks?) or is this a better job for jug?  Based on suggestions on SO, I spent a few days trying to use Jug, but the number of iterations in my nested for-loops easily gets into the 10's of millions (and more) of very fast transactions, so the author recommends against this.

Comment: You don't provide enough information: what is the dependency of "some criteria" ? does it depend on one of the "vlad"s ? i ? both ? all ? I we had this information we might be able to create a recursive function that aggregates the intermediate results and calls recursively with the "rest"

Comment: @alfasin I provided the conditional logic.  I will research your suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use `itertools.product` with multiprocessing-map:

```
import csv
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product

def crunchnumber(values):
    if some criteria:
        sol = values[0][2]+values[1][2]+values[2][2].... 
        return sol

def process(datas):
    "takes data1, ..., datan as a list"
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.map_async(crunchnumber, product(*datas))
    print [a for a in result if a is not None]
```

Comment: I will dig into itertools.product

Comment: ah, very cool, it looks like i need to use product() in place of my first 2 loops and combination() in place of my last 3 loops.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly I am passing with product(*datas) and what is originally being passed into process(datas)?  do I invoke with process()?  How exactly is the csv data being passed?  I understand a lot more of how multiprocess works with map, and how product() works, but If you could expand a bit, I think I am close to having a foundation that I can build upon.

Comment: @nodoze: it is normally a design error, to have numbered variable names. So the correct way is to put `data1`, `data2`, ... into a list `datas = [data1, data2, ...]`.